# read from stdin in sbt task

Tags: scala, sbt

Suppose I have the following code

```
object Cli extends App {
  Iterator.continually(StdIn.readLine()).takeWhile(!_.equals("quit")).foreach { command =>
    println(s"[$command RESULT] " + ApiClient.executeCommand(command))
  }
}
```

and custom sbt command

```
val cli = inputKey[Unit]("Run client")
cli := {
  "java -cp my.jar Cli".!
}
```

If I run "java -cp my.jar Cli" from console, it works fine. But when I call "sbt cli" it fails with NullPointerException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Cli$$anonfun$2.apply(Cli.scala:14)
```

How to define sbt task to read commands from stdin?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `build.sbt`

```
fork := true
```

See http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Forking.html